# Emacs: (Almost) random crashes about 2-3 times a day on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

I am a happy Emacs user on Mac OS X for almost a year now. The problem is that I experience almost random crashes of Emacs several times. My setup is:

GNU Emacs 24.0.95.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) [installed as Emacs-pretest-24.0.95-universal-10.6.8 from http://emacsformacosx.com/builds ] on Mac OS X 10.7.3. (The reason for Emacs 24 is because of the latest features in Gnus).

The main problem is of course that I can't track down the reasons why Emacs crashes. Sometimes it crashes when I capture a new event in org-mode, today it crashed when I added an attachment to an open email in Gnus per drag-and-drop -- both tasks I frequently do without problems. The only hint I found is http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-cause-of-an-Emacs-crash-on-OS-X so it seems I am not alone.

Assume Emacs crashed and I reopened it. If I double-click a file in Finder (to be opened in Emacs), the file doesn't open. I rather get a buffer showing a file I loaded at some previous point in time. If I double-click the file in Finder again, it is then opened. I have to do this for every new file I would like to open. The simple solution is that after a crash I open Emacs, close it normally, and open it again. It then runs fine -- until the next crash :-)

I know this is far too vague to be useful to ask (?), but I would like to know if this is a problem specific to my setup, specific to the Mac, or Emacs 24. So if anyone experiences similar crashes, it would be good to know. Two linux guys told me that they experience crashes about once a month, so I guess there is room for improvement :-)

Comment: Have you tried other distributions as well, such as [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/)?

Comment: I started with Aquamacs. After about 4 weeks I switched to Gnu Emacs (after the advice of many people). I realized soon that certain "features" of Aquamacs were just wrong for me and overall I'm glad I switched. Aquamacs did not crash but I did not use it that extensively either. Going back to Aquamacs is not an option for me anymore anyway. Overall, my suspicion is that either Gnus or org-mode or a combination of the two lead to the crashes. But I really don't know. I also checked the message buffer but couldn't find anything useful on the crashes.

Comment: Have you used Console.app to check the system logs and crash reports for further clues?

Comment: I remember I had the idea once. Not sure why I didn't check. Good point, I'll do that after the next crash and will report here.

Comment: Ahhh... I still see a crash in the log-files :-) Today, 12:48 -- and it was org-mode! Okay, I'm just not sure it was a real crash, but let me wait until the next crash to make 100% sure I identify the right thing. I'll report after the next crash then.

Comment: BTW, this isn't the right forum to be asking this kind of question as it's not programming related.  Suggest trying http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or one of the emacs support groups.

Comment: Okay, thanks Ned. I'll explore the problem a bit more and then ask on either apple.stackexchange or in the Emacs forum.

Comment: Check this suggestion on the Emacs Wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MacOSTweaks#toc19

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I could solve it by deleting all of the [preference files](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/mac_os_x_corrupt_preference_files) regarding Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

If it crashes, the problem is not in your config.  The problem might be *triggered* by your config, but the problem is definitely in Emacs itself.  So please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug` so we can try and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the bug-report, Marius, and for helping us track it down.  For stackoverflow's benefit, the bug-report is at http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11257 and the end result is apparently that you can't reliably run under Mac OS X 10.7 an Emacs compiled in Mac OS X 10.6 (and I suspect the same might happen for other Mac OS X releases).